# Binding KnockoutJS to Radio Button with computed

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a question with an array of answers.  Each answer has a boolean property called isRight, which represents whether the answer is...right.

I'm trying to render a radio button for each answer, and have it be checked if that answer is right.  If the user clicks a different button, that answer becomes correct.

I understand that KO binds the checked property to a value, and each radio button will only be checked if the radio's value matches the bound value; you can't just bind directly to isRight.

I put a computedObservable on the question itself, which should do all that.  And it works.  The problem is, I want to subscribe to the **change** event of the radio button, to see when a new answer is selected (and send an ajax request).  The problem I'm having is that the ko binding is not updated in the change handler.  It seems putting a delay in the handler will give me what I want, but I'd prefer a more direct solution.

And it seems the click event works perfectly, but that'll fire each time a radio button is clicked, even if it's already checked.

Is there any way to ensure that the binding is updated in the change event?  Current code is ko 2.0, and I've also tried 2.1.

[**Full Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PC4aF/1/)

---

Full Source:

```
function Question() {
    this.name = "My Question";

    var i = 0;
    this.answers = ko.observableArray([
        new Answer(++i, "Answer 1", false),
        new Answer(++i, "Answer 2", true),
        new Answer(++i, "Answer 3", false)]);

    this.correctAnswer = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            for (var i = 0, max = this.answers().length; i < max; i++)
                if (this.answers()[i].isRight())
                    return "answer-" + this.answers()[i].id();
        },
        write: function (newValue) {
            var newId = +newValue.split('-')[1];
            for (var i = 0, max = this.answers().length; i < max; i++)
                this.answers()[i].isRight(this.answers()[i].id() === newId);
        },
        owner: this
    });
}


function Answer(id, name, isRight) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.isRight = ko.observable(isRight);
}

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new Question());

    $(document).on("change", "input[type='radio']", function () {
        var answer = ko.dataFor(this);
        var isRight = answer.isRight();

        setTimeout(function () { alert("before = " + isRight + "  after = " + answer.isRight()); }, 1000);
    });
});
```

---

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="text:name"></div>
<div data-bind="foreach:answers">
    <label>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <input type="radio" name="uniqueQuestionName" data-bind="value: 'answer-' + id(), checked:$parent.correctAnswer" />
    </label>
    <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a specific reason to subscribe to the "change" event, you might want to consider using a [manual subscription](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables) to an observable that is changing.  This way you can be notified whenever the actual data is changed.

Here is a sample that uses a slightly different approach: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/FvZXj/.  It uses a function to handle setting the value, which passes the current answer as the first argument.  It then uses that to properly set `isRight` and an observable `correctAnswer` that you could subscribe against.

Comment: I considered that, but the real example has a collection of questions, some bound initially, and some added dynamically.  I really don't want to try to keep track of all questions and maintain subscriptions as new ones are added.  One idea I had was to subscribe to afterRender, but I didn't see a way to link that to a (non-global) function that was outside of my ViewModel.  If there's a way to do *that*, I might be able to do the manual subscription thing rather easily.

Comment: I would create a function at the root level to do your AJAX request and then create the subscription to the correct answer of each question as a natural part of creating a new Question instance.  Maybe I am not quite understanding your scenario enough, but you would not need to manage any subscriptions as they would be a part of any question object. I might be missing part of it though :)

Comment: I see.  We made a choice to keep AJAX requests out of our view models, but that's a decision we might have to reconsider.  For now though, we're changing our DB structure to match what KO wants (we're early in dev cycle) - each question will have a correctAnswerId - easy peasy

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help as always. Just a brief question: even simplifying the radio buttons to be bound the "normal way", no computed, just a plain observable, still has the change event not working. The change event does however work for a textbox. Is this guarenteed, or is it nondeterministic and just happens to usually work? We'll prolly end up ditching dom changes, but I'd just like to know if textboxes can be counted on to fire their change event after the ko binding is updated.

Comment: Looks like this happens, because the `change` event is fired before `click`.  KO binds to `change` for a text input (`value` binding).  For a radio, it binds to `click`.  From your original sample, you could change your handler to bind to `click` and get the value that you are looking for.

Comment: As for the AJAX calls, you could still keep them outside your model.  You could even trigger an event from inside your view model and respond to it outside.

Comment: Yeah - I saw that `click` worked before, but I wanted to use `change` since that way it would only fire when the value actually changed, and not when the user just for no reason clicked on an already clicked radio button.  But I think this is probably the easiest problem to work around. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Also - please consider adding that to the documentation.  Responding to dom events with $().on is fairly common, and users may be confused as to why their view models aren't up to date.

Comment: As an aside, it doesn't seem safe for radio buttons to rely on the 'click' event changing them, since I can also select a radio box by tabbing to the control and hitting the space bar to select it.