# Binding a radio button through the $parent binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm generating radio buttons in a `foreach` loop.  I'm trying to bind the checked property to a basic observable in the parent.  Unfortunately when clicking on a radio button the parent's property doesn't seem to be updated in the click handler.

Based on some [previous work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283580/binding-knockoutjs-to-radio-button-with-computed#comment13234822_10285883), it seems the click handler should be an acceptable place to grab the updated value on the view model.  Most curiously, it seems after you click through the radio buttons a few times the right values start to come out.

[Full Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PC4aF/4/)

Code:

```
function Question() {
    this.name = "My Question";

    this.answers = ko.observableArray([
        new Answer(1, "Answer 1", false),
        new Answer(2, "Answer 2", true),
        new Answer(3, "Answer 3", false)]);

    this.correctAnswer = ko.observable(2);
}

function Answer(id, name, isRight) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.isRight = ko.observable(isRight);
}

ko.applyBindings(new Question());

$(document).on("click", "input[type='radio']", function () {
     var answer = ko.dataFor(this);
     var question = ko.contextFor(this).$parent;

     var answerId = answer.id();
     var correctAnswer = question.correctAnswer();

     alert(answerId + " should equal " + correctAnswer + 
           (answerId === correctAnswer ? " SWEET" : " DAMNIT"));
});
​
```

HTML

```
<div data-bind="text:name"></div>
<div data-bind="foreach:answers">
    <label>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <input type="radio" name="X" data-bind="value: id, checked:$parent.correctAnswer" />
    </label>
    <br />
</div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

When you bind the checked value to the $parent.correctAnswer, it's a two way binding which means you update the correct answer to be whatever you click.

I suggest replacing it with something like:

```
checked:$parent.isCorrectAnswer()
```

Which is a ko.computed which always returns the correct answer, but also can alert you when the selected value changes

```
this.isCorrectAnswer= ko.computed(function () {        
    alert('your message');
    return 2;//return correct answer
});
```

Code is untested and provided to get you going :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
answerId === correctAnswer
```

to

```
answerId == correctAnswer
```

for it to work correctly every time.

Hope this helps!